# Finding Employee Count For Each Month In MDX

Tags: mdx

```
            WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Active Employee] as

    FILTER(
    [Date].[YQMD].CURRENTMEMBER.children
    , [Employee].[Activation Date].CURRENTMEMBER.children<=[Date].[YQMD].CURRENTMEMBER and [Employee].[De Activation Date].CURRENTMEMBER.children>=[Date].[YQMD].CURRENTMEMBER).count

    select
    {[Active Employee]} on 0,
    {[Date].[YQMD].CURRENTMEMBER.children} on 1
    from
    [Operational]
```

I need to find the number of employees for each month In MDX

consider a employee1 joined on jan 2014
count of employees in jan 1
count of employees in feb 1
consider a employee2 joined on march 2014
count of employees in march 2
employee1 left in april
count of employees in april 1

Comment: How do the keys for the attributes used in the `[Date].[YQMD]` hierarchy look like? Which data type? Could you give samples? same question for `[Employee].[Activation Date]`. What are the names of the levels of the `[Date].[YQMD]` hierarchy?

Comment: What [Measures] do you have available? I think this calculation may need to be done in the data mart.

Comment: Thanks FrankPL &  Magnus, I figured it out